# Hidden project-level setting in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I was trying to fix 'failed gradle sync' error and found out that the **project-level setting** is somehow not shown up in **File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Gradle**. I have tried to reinstall Android Studio and create new project but none of them worked. Are there anyways to fix this?[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWGml.png)